# How I can use com.android.camera.action.CROP with unspecified output size?

Tags: android, image, crop

Usually com.android.camera.action.CROP will show device's crop action, I have tried but it require specified output size. Is there any simplest way to perform croping action without specified output size like [IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView](https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView) or [steelkiwi/cropiwa](https://github.com/steelkiwi/cropiwa/)?

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 360);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 360);
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Usually com.android.camera.action.CROP will show device's crop action

No. Frequently it will crash with an `ActivityNotFoundException`. [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html), and many Android devices will not ship with a camera app, or any other app, offering `com.android.camera.action.CROP`. Beyond that, `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is undocumented, and so what extras are honored, and what those extras mean, will vary by activity.

> Is there any simplest way to perform croping action without specified output size

Find and use [an image-cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) that offers the feature set that you desire. You appear to list two of them in your question.